# Trouble making a query with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, wildcard, sql-like, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-api

Well guys I hope you're doing fine in this epidemic times, I'm having trouble in neglecting special characters in a query at elasticsearch : 
Here is what I want to do :

```
Select * from table where ext like %6500% and start_time like %-01-%
```

Here is what I did:

```
   "query": {
       "bool": {
           "must": [
               {
                   "query_string": {
                       "ext": "*6500*",
                       "fields": [
                           "extension"
                       ],
                       "analyze_wildcard": true
                   }
               },
               {
                   "query_string": {
                       "query": "*\\-01\\-*",
                       "fields": [
                           "start_time"
                       ],
                       "analyze_wildcard": true
                   }
               }
           ]
       }
   }
```

The first one works but the second doesn't give what I want. Btw the field start_time is like this for example: 2020-01-03 15:03:45 and it's a heyword type (I found it like that).

Comment: Can you add your mapping

Comment: they are Keywords

Comment: can you a sample document and also mapping as you got it from Get <indexname>/_mapping

Comment: {"mappings":{"properties":{"answer_time":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}}} @jaspreetchahal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indexing your field with type text and sub fields of keyword type. Text fields are broken in tokens ex "2020-01-12" will be stored as ["2020","01","12"]. You need to run your query on keyword field using "start_time.keyword"

```
{
  "query": {
       "bool": {
           "must": [
               {
                   "query_string": {
                       "query": "*-01-*",
                       "fields": [
                           "start_time.keyword" --> note
                       ],
                       "analyze_wildcard": true
                   }
               }
           ]
       }
   }
}
```

As @joe mentioned wildcard queries have poor performance it is better to use date field

Answer (score 0):

If you're forced to use the `keyword` type in your `start_time`, the following works -- no need for the leading & trailing wildcards since your `start_time` will adhere to a certain format:

```
GET karim/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "-01-",
            "fields": [
              "start_time"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

It's advisable, though, to use `date` whenever working with date(time)s. So set your index up like so:

```
PUT karim
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "start_time": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and query like so

```
GET karim/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "start_time": {
              "gte": "01",
              "lt": "02",
              "format": "MM"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

for the month of January of any given year. Adjust the format to match a specific year etc.

This approach is guaranteed to be faster than wildcard textual queries, esp. when you're querying multiple ranges and, possibly, intend to aggregate down the road.

Comment: Thank you for responding, actually I'm doing a bulk request every day of data taken from a local IPBX server, i used the Elasticsearch java API to do so, and while searching for putting mappings, I've had errors saying that mappings are deprecated and index already created so on... knowinh that i put the mapping as advicesd in the documentation, so I left it as it is, intending to work with it as I thought I could in the question but didn't work, now I'm dumping all the indexes and reindexing them with slicing the date : doing the year, mounth, day each in a single parameter.

Comment: OK. So are you saying the question is not relevant anymore?

Comment: Yes I tried the method that you gave me but unfortunaletly it didn't work for me